# Is it possible to connect to AuraDB with neomodel?

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

Is it possible to connect to AuraDB with `neomodel`?

AuraDB connection URI is like `neo4j+s://xxxx.databases.neo4j.io`.
This is not contained user/password information.

However, connection config of neomodel is bolt and it is contained user/password information.
`config.DATABASE_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687'`

Comment: the equivalence of bolt in Aura is neo4j+s while localhost:7687 is similar to URI. Thus you can still connect from python neomodel to neo4j aura by using neoj4+s://neo4j:password@uri format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connecting to neo4j Aura uses neo4j+s protocol so you need to use the provided uri by Aura.

Reference: https://neo4j.com/developer/python/#driver-configuration

In example below; you can set the database url by setting the userid and password along with the uri. It works for me so it should also work for you.

```
from neomodel import config

user = 'neo4j'
psw = 'awesome_password'
uri = 'awesome.databases.neo4j.io'
    
config.DATABASE_URL = 'neo4j+s://{}:{}@{}'.format(user, psw, uri)
print(config.DATABASE_URL)

Result: 

   neo4j+s://neo4j:awesome_password@awesome.databases.neo4j.io
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be

```
user = os.environ['NEO4J_USERNAME']
pswd = os.environ['NEO4J_PASSWORD']
uri = os.environ['NEO4J_URI']

from neo4j import GraphDatabase
driver = GraphDatabase().driver(uri, auth=(user, pswd))
config.DRIVER = driver

from neomodel import db

db.set_connection(driver=driver)
db.cypher_query("RETURN 'Hello World' as message")
```

This way you can directly use the Auradb uri, without the need to  extrapolate the username and password between the protocol and the url part of the URI.